# What does it do?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm quite new in JavaScript and jQuery, can someone please explain to me what this lines of code do? if is possible if someone can write in detail explanation...
For instance, what is function (context) - is context representing the attributes/properties such as jQ: trummedVal: etc... or?

```
var servis = false;

var FormData = function () {
var topThat = this;
this.trimValue = function (control) {
    return typeof control.val() !== 'undefined' ? control.val().trim() : control.val();
},
this.transportMode= {
    jQ: $('#transportMode'),
    trimmedVal: function () { return topThat.trimValue($('#transportMode')); },
    name: "Type of transport",
    mandatory: !servis && true,
    hookupEvents: function (context) {
        // populating order data
        if ($(".newApp").length != 0) {
            context.jQ.change(function () {
                if (topThat.ctrId.trimmedVal() !== '')
                    topThat.populateOrderData();

                if ($(this).val().trim() === "TRUCK")
                    $(".reg").show();
                else {
                    $(".reg").hide();
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
$(document).ready(function () {

if ($("#servis").length > 0)
    servis = true;

var page = new FormData();
page.init();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not complete, and your question is somewhat general. You should be more specific about what you have and what you want. Here’s an answer to your particular question:

In `function (context) { ... }`, *context* is a parameter to the function. Inside the function `hookupEvents`, you can use `context` as a reference to whatever argument was passed to the function.

If you call `hookupEvents(window)`, then the `context` variable inside the function will be a reference to `window`. You could also call `hookupEvents('arg')`; variable`context` inside the function will then be a string containing “arg”.

Comment: ok, to be specific, what are these: jQ: trimmedVal: mandatory: hookupEvents: ? are those attribures or? also I saw that they are assigned to this.transportMode= {} I presume that "transportMode" is an property which can be called later, or?

Comment: @dovla091: Those are property names in an object literal. If you don't know what the *syntax* means, you should read a tutorial, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide. Stack Overflow is not the right place to *learn a language*.

Comment: I agree, but it is a good place to direct people where they could get an additional explanation such as documentations, or something has changed lately on this forum...?